# JQuery Datatables makeEditable() issues with large dataset

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-plugins, datatables

I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165410/ASP-NET-MVC-Editable-DataTable-jQuery-DataTables-a) to implement cell editing in JQuery datatables with MVC4.

Links to the plugins used are:

1. jQuery [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) plug-in v1.7.5., including the optional DataTables
   CSS style-sheets used for applying the default styles on the page
2. jQuery [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) plug-in v1.6.2., required for inline cell editing
3. jQuery [validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plug-in v1.7., for implementation of client-side
   validation
4. jQuery [DataTables](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jquery-datatables-editable/) Editable plug-in that integrates all these
   mentioned plug-ins into a fully functional editable datatable.

To achieve the effect of creating the editable datatable you simply have to include the following as part of your script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#myDataTable').dataTable().makeEditable();
    });
</script>
```

---

### The Problem

For each column present in the grid an event is created in the DOM to allow editing.

Where the dataset is very large this has proven to cause significant issues even crashing my browser.

---

### The overall question

Is it possible to only call the edit logic when the user selects the appropriate column rather than trying to build up a large amount of events in the DOM?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library, however i suggest to check if the views and stored procedure is supported, after that you can customize the number of columns required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to @CMedina 's answer, please read:

[.on() - Direct and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> In addition to their ability to handle events on descendant elements not yet created, another advantage of delegated events is their potential for much lower overhead when many elements must be monitored.

On a data table with 1,000 `td` elements in `#example`, this example attaches a handler to 1,000 elements:

```
$("#example td").on("click",function(){
    $(this).editable();
})
```

An event-delegation approach attaches an event handler to only one element, the `#example`, and the event only needs to bubble up one level (from the clicked `td` to `#example`):

```
$("#example").on("click", "td", function(){
    $(this).editable();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use makeEditable() with very large datasets, but you might get a performance benefit from an uplift of some of your versions. I am using:

- jquery 1.6.4
- datatables 1.8.2
- jeditable 1.7.3
- jQuery Validation Plugin 1.11.1
- datatables.editable 2.3.1

Comment: just to add, you could use aocolumns to make columns editable on initialisation, but the datatables docs suggest they can't be changed thereafter. You could reload the page to edit a particular column, but that's poor UX

Comment: The main problem is that they are not massive datasets, around 4000 rows give or take a 1000. Now my initial reaction is that with event delegation this could be resolved but unfortunately I'm not handy with plugins and this leaves me in a bind. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Essentially what you would like to do is bind methods to one column, and unbind methods from the other. That's a significant number of events firing every time you want to switch, similar in magnitude to the number of events firing at load time (a proportion of the number of columns on-screen). Updating your libraries may result in fewer events being fired with improved jquery, with little programming cost.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is add the event when the user clicking in the td.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

    $("#example td").on("click",function(){
        $(this).editable();
    })

});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/32/

Now, if you do not want to edit all the columns you can assign the event editable only for some columns per class

```
var oTable = $('#table_id').dataTable(
    {
         "bSort": false,
         "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    });

$('td.editable_class', oTable.fnGetNodes()).editable('editable.php', {
"callback": function( sValue, y ) {
    var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );
    oTable.fnUpdate( sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1] );
},
"submitdata": function ( value, settings ) {
    return {
        "row_id": $(this).data('id'),
        "column": $(this).data('column'),
    };
},
"height": "17px",
"width": "100%",
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `td` editable on click:

```
$("#example td").on("click",function(){
    $(this).editable();
})
```